# Как правильно перебрать многомерный массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста,  **как правильно перебрать многомерный массив**.

У меня первый и последний элемент выводится как `string` если я не ошибаюсь.

**Почему так происходит?**

Если возможно, опишите ваше решение подрoбно.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [2, 5, 3, [32, 5, [23, 6, [3, 8, 0, [13]]]], 3], 7, 4];

var item;

for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
 item = arr[i];
  document.write(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тебе нужно использовать рекурсию:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [2, 5, 3, [32, 5, [23, 6, [3, 8, 0, [13]]]], 3], 7, 4];

function foreachArr(arr) { //в ф-цию передаем массив
  arr.forEach(function(item) { //перебираем массив
    //если элемент массива является вложенным массивом - вызываем нашу ф-цию (будет рекурсия)
    if (Array.isArray(item)) foreachArr(item);
    else document.write(item); //иначе - выводим элемент
  });
}
foreachArr(arr);
```

Comment: спасибо @Rysinsky Valentine